# Adding client secret and client id to request in API Gateway

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an Auth server sitting behind my Spring Cloud Gateway. I want to perform JWT auth through the Gateway. When I call the respective API Endpoint, I'm having to pass my username, password, client-id and client-secret to generate a JWT token.

User simply calls the endpoint with username and password, and the API gateway forwards the request to the Auth server after attaching client-id and client-secret. This is my whole plan.

My question is, how can I attach client id and client secret to my request, using Spring Cloud Gateway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do client id and client secret come from?

Comment: I have created an OAuth2.0 with server microservice. That's where my client id and client password come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a java configuration as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/oauth/token")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/oauth/token")
                        .id("auth"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

In this case, the original request and response will simply be proxied through the spring cloud gateway.

For example, if spring cloud gateway is running on port 8080, the request will be (the authorization server is running on port 8081):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic c2VydmVyX2FwcDpzZWNyZXQ=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=server_app'
```

You can add client-id, client-secret, or other data on the client.

If you need to modify the request body you can add a filter:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/oauth/token")
                        .filters(f -> f.modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                (exchange, body) -> {
                                    String modifiedBody = someService.modify(body);
                                    return Mono.just(modifiedBody);
                                })
                        )
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/oauth/token")
                        .id("auth"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This i know. But here the user specifies client id and password in the request itself. In my question, the user provides only username and password. The spring cloud gateway will be adding the client id and client password to the request

Comment: In the edit, you are downstreaming the client-id and client-secret that are received from the request itself, right? I'm looking for a solution in which the curl does not contain client-id and client-secret. I want those two to be added to the downstreaming request, by the gateway

Comment: I'm not sure whether I misunderstood client id and client secret. Should I enforce client-id, client-secret checks for users? or should i turn it off?

Comment: In the last example, I modify the body using a filter. You can use this filter to add client-id or client-secret to the body. If necessary, you can add/change the title in the same way. Additional checks depend on the application logic, but in any case, the authorization service will check the correctness.

Comment: This auth server is used by the  user and not by client applications. So, is there any point in mandating client-id and client-secret?

Thanks for your edit!

Comment: is there any way to achieve the same thing you mentioned in the comment using yml configuration?

Comment: As indicated in the instructions, there is no way to modify the body via yml - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#modify-a-request-body-gatewayfilter-factory ("This filter can be configured only by using the Java DSL.")

Comment: What should i replace the "someservice" with?

Comment: For example, if you set: MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, you can replace this string with: String modifiedBody = "client-id=test_client&client-secret=secret"; But it depends on your authorization service.

Comment: String modifiedBody = someService.modify(body);
This someService is my question. Thank you

Comment: SomeService refers to a class in the spring cloud gateway application that can be used to modify the body. This is just an example, you can delete someService and write a string instead depending on your MediaType.

Comment: thank you! I've posted another question, could you please have a look at that too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157151/spring-cloud-gateway-load-balancing-makes-requests-slow